# Difference between "run everyday" and "running everyday" after "One thing you can do is."

Tags: gerunds

"One thing you can do is running every day" and "One thing you can do is run everyday"
Any difference? Both correct or one is wrong?

Comment: Both correct informally, though some may prefer a to-infinitive and open-form 'every day' here.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be either "One thing you can do is go running every day" or "One thing you can do is run every day", because one can't "running", but you can run or go running. I hope this helps!